# wrap number of div according to odd or even

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have number of div (number of div is dynamic)

for eg:

```
<div> div1 </div>
<div> div2 </div>
<div> div3 </div>
<div> div4 </div>
<div> div5 </div>
<div> div6 </div>
<div> div7 </div>
```

int the above div i want wrap those div according to the number of the div odd or even

in the above case its number of div is odd

i want to be like this

```
<div clss="wrap">
    <div> div1 </div>
    <div> div2 </div>
    <div> div3 </div>
    <div> div4 </div>
</div 

<div clss="wrap">
    <div> div5 </div>
    <div> div6 </div>
    <div> div7 </div>
</div
```

i have created following function

```
     var a = $('.vidoes > .box');
     var numItems = $('.box').length

     if (numItems % 2 != 0) {

         alert("odd");
     }


    below code is to wrap div's


     for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += number) {
     a.slice(i, i + number).wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>');
 }
```

after all

if the number of div is odd eg: number of div 7 its should wrap 4 div inside first wrap and 3 div inside second wrap if the number of div is 11 its should wrap 6 div inside first wrap and 5 div inside second wrap if the number of div in even it should wrap equally in two wrap

the number of wrap also dynamic may wrap is 3  it should be 3 inside first wrap and 3 inside second wrap and  1 inside last wrap

Comment: How does the wrapping depend upon whether there's an odd, or even, number of div elements?

Comment: well the same list of div`s could be grouped as 6 and  1 right

Comment: if the number of div is odd eg: number of div 7 its should wrap 4 div inside first wrap and 3 div inside second wrap if the number of div is 11 its should wrap 6 div inside first wrap and 5 div inside second wrap  if the number of div in even it should wrap equally in two wrap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.slice()` method:

```
var $a = $('.vidoes > .box'), 
    $f = $a.slice(0, Math.ceil($a.length / 2))
           .wrapAll('<div class="videoswraper"/>');

$a.not($f).wrapAll('<div class="videoswraper"/>');
```

edit: For wrapping each set of 3 elements with a wrapper element you can a `while` loop:

```
while ( $('.vidoes > .box').length ) {
   $('.vidoes > .box').slice(0, 3).wrapAll('<div class="videoswraper">')
}
```

Note that wrapper elements shouldn't have `box` className, otherwise something bad will happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/PzeHg/

Comment: this is only warping the first number of div the second number of div just outside the wrap

Comment: sory ,actually your code is  working  that was my problem, now if we want to wrap is 3 it should be 3 inside first wrap and 3 inside second wrap and 1 inside last wrap, i mean number of wrap is also dynamic

Comment: if 
<div class="box"> div1 </div>
<div class="box"> div2 </div>
<div class="box"> div3 </div>
<div class="box"> div4 </div>
<div class="box"> div5 </div>
<div class="box"> div6 </div>
<div class="box"> div7 </div>
<div class="box"> div8 </div>
<div class="box"> div9 </div>
<div class="box"> div10 </div>

it will wrap in 4 that mean 3 in each wrap and 1 in last wrap

i actauly want to wrap all these above div into 3 wrap  if the wrapper number is 4 all all of thease above divs should wrap into 4 wraper

Comment: in my cas number of div is not important number of wrap is important if number of wrap 4 calculate length of the div's and wrap asper the length

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ut8Kr/)</kbd>

```
var div_all = $('#container div'), //cache sector for all div's
    num = Math.round(div_all.length / 2); //get 1/2 count of div and round it
div_all.slice(0, num).wrapAll('<div class ="wrap"/>');//wrapAll div's from 0 to num
div_all.slice(num).wrapAll('<div class ="wrap"/>'); //wrapAll rest of div's
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div>div1</div>
    <div>div2</div>
    <div>div3</div>
    <div>div4</div>
    <div>div5</div>
    <div>div6</div>
    <div>div7</div>
</div>
```

---

[.wrapAll()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

[.slice(begin[, end])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

[Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: actaully this answer is almost near and now the number of wrap also dynamic may wrap is 3  it should be 3 inside first wrap and 3 inside second wrap and  1 inside last wrap